# how to prevent exception null value from retrieving records using Oledb

Tags: c#, listview, dbnull

```
    while(r.Read())
    {
      ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(r.GetString(2));
      item.SubItems.Add(r.GetString(3));
      item.SubItems.Add(r.GetString(4));
      item.SubItems.Add(r.GetString(5));
      item.SubItems.Add(r.GetString(6));
      item.SubItems.Add(r.GetString(7));
      item.SubItems.Add(r.GetString(8));
      item.SubItems.Add(r.GetString(11));
      lsvListOfBooks.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

this code fills a listview with records.
but if the cell from the database is null,
it throws exception

```
Specified cast is not valid
```

and exits the thread and the rest of the records won't be displayed.

how can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that null values in result columns are represented by a different type - `DBNull` to be precise - and it cannot be trivially cast to a `string`.

The simplest solution to this is to create an extension for the `IDataReader` interface that will detect `DBNull` values and convert them.  Add this class to your code:

```
public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static string GetNullableString(this IDataReader self, int ordinal)
    {
        return self.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : self.GetString(ordinal);
    }
}
```

Now you can replace `GetString` with `GetNullableString` in your code and it should function as expected.  The `IsDBNull` call will detect the null condition and return null instead of throwing an error.

Unfortunately this sort of thing is required for all of the data types.  If a null value is valid for the field the `IDataReader` will use `DBNull` values that are incompatible with any of the nullable types.